# PHP Wamp is not finding a file which exists

Tags: php, wamp

I'm having a critical issue where my WAMP installation for PHP 5.3.0 is not finding a file which exists within my computer. Does anyone know anything about this? Possibly a PHP Bug?
Any help would be much appreciated.

Here is the variable which creates the file:

`$baseNewsUrl   = "C:/reviews/reviews/$platform/$fullname";`

And here is the code which grabs the contents:

```
if(is_file($baseNewsUrl)){
    $contents = file_get_contents($baseNewsUrl);
} else {
    echo "File not found. " . "\r\n";
    continue;
}
```

Here is the output of `$baseNewsUrl`: C:/reviews/reviews/GBA/r20107_GBA.htm
And the file does exist.

Comment: Did you check the permission of the file?

Comment: It's nearly impossible to help you without some knowledge of the code you're using and the file-structure.

Comment: Giving us more information would be helpful. Where is the file you are trying to find? Can you show us the code that is trying to read it? My first inclination is that the file is located somewhere that PHP or the user it runs as does not have permission to read (for security).

Comment: I've editted the question to include the variables and function calls.

Comment: ALso, can you output `$baseNewsURL` and try to acces the path manually? Are you 100% sure the file exists? Maybe $platform or $fullname are not set in the context you are using them in?

Comment: Modify your else cause to read: `echo "File not found: " . $baseNewsUrl . "\r\n";` and post the results.

Comment: I've added the output for $baseNewsURL and I can access the path manually.

Comment: Just to exclude the possibility, this is all taking place on one and the same computer, right? No virtual machine or remote server in play?

Comment: Can you do a `error_reporting(E_ALL);` in the beginning of the script and see what `file_get_contents()` gives you?

Comment: Remember that just because you can access the file doesn't mean Apache can access the file.  Make sure the WAMP is running as Local System or that its account/group appears in the `C:\reviews` security settings.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's due to Windows Vista and WAMP.

Answer (score 0):

Check that the entire path leading up to your file is readable by the user PHP is running as (if you are using IIS, this might be something like "Network Service," although I am not particularly experienced with PHP on Windows). Also, check whether the INI directives "open_basedir" or perhaps "safe_mode" are set--these would give PHP self-imposed limits on which files are accessible.

Answer (score 0):

Do a var_dump (not an echo) on your variable.

```
var_dump($baseNewsUrl);
```

and look at the actual contents.  You may have some invisible garbage characters in there that's preventing Windows if you're doing this in a browser to make sure there's no empty tags (or other browser-render-invisible) characters.

If that doesn't reveal anything, remove the `is_file` check and try to open the file with file_get_contents (or any file related function) and var_dump it's contents.  You'll either open the file, or PHP will spit out an error/warning/notice (either to your browser or to your error log) that should let you know why it can't open the file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna say this, and it very well might not be your problem but it is a recurring one for me. If you use skype on your computer, it has a somewhat known compatibility issue with WAMP. It cause's WAMP to be unstable, not load files properly.. everything.

Answer (score 0):

on windows

```
$baseNewsUrl = "C:\\reviews\\reviews\\$platform\\$fullname";
```

Comment: You should ALWAYS use the frontslash character for accessing path names in PHP. "C:/reviews/reviews/$platform/$fullname" is the preferred way to access files.